# What is meant by $\log_2 X \sim N(0,n) \implies \log X \sim N(0, n (\log 2)^2)$?

Tags: logarithms, normal-distribution

I see the following written in my class notes:

> $\log_2 X \sim N(0,n) \implies \log X \sim N(0, n (\log 2)^2)$

But I don't understand what they did here. It looked like they did some kind of conversion of the base on the log, but what is the base on the log on the RHS?

Comment: Presumably it's a natural log, but this will work for a log of any base

Comment: @StephenDonovan So shouldn't the variance become

\begin{align}
    \log_2(n) = \frac{\log_e(n)}{\log_e(2)}
\end{align}
? 
How did it become $n(\log 2)^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y = \log_2X \sim N(0, n)$.

By using a formula

$$
\log_2X = \frac{\log X}{\log 2}, \text{ where } \log X \text{ is the natural }\log \text{ of }X,
$$

one obtains that

$$
\log X = \log{2}\cdot \log_2{X} = \log{2}\cdot Y.
$$

Then, we can use a property of the Normal distribution

$$
\text{If }Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2), \text{ then }aY\sim N(a\mu, a^2\sigma^2). 
$$

In our case, we have

$$
Y = \log_2X \sim N(0, n), a = \log{2}\Rightarrow aY = \log{X} \sim N(0, n(\log{2})^2). 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall from algebra, $a^{\log_a b} = b \to \log_a b \ln a= \ln b \to \log_a b = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}.$ So, we can rewrite our variable $log_2 X$ as $\frac{1}{\ln 2} \ln X.$

We know that if we have a variable $A \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $cA \sim N(c\mu, c^2\sigma^2).$

So, if $log_2 X \sim N(0, n),$ then $\ln2 * \log_2 X = \ln X \sim N(0, n(\ln 2)^2).$